# Should I include the header containing the definition of a namespace in source files?

Tags: c++, namespaces

If I have a namespace defined in a header file and in some source files I don't include that header but instead define a namespace with the same name as the one in the header and declare the same members as in the header file then add definitions then am I defining a new namespace or opening the existing one?

```
//file.h
#ifndef FILE_H_INCLUDED
#define FILE_H_INCLUDED

namespace mylibNS{
    void foo();
    void bar();
}

#endif // FILE_H_INCLUDED

// foo.cpp
#include <iostream>
//#include "file.h"

namespace mylibNS{
    void foo();
}

void mylibNS::foo(){
    std::cout << "foo()\n";
}

// bar.cpp
#include <iostream>
// #include "file.h"

namespace mylibNS{
    void bar();
}

void mylibNS::bar(){
    std::cout << "bar()\n";
}

// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "file.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    mylibNS::bar();
    mylibNS::foo();
}
```

- The code above works fine although in source files `foo.cpp` and `bar.cpp` I didn't include the header `file.h` containing the definition of namespace `mylibNS`! So in those source files am I opening an existing namespace or defining a new one in each file? The program works just fine so should I do it this way or stick to the standard (opening the namespace and adding to it)?
- Should I include `file.h` in `foo.cpp` and `bar.cpp` and `main.cpp`?

Comment: I follow the *include what you use* rule.  I also sometimes make header-header files (`*.hh`) to put forward declares there.  I also have a 1:1 ratio for header file to source file, rather than having one header file that declares things which are defined in different source files.  And finally, the *very* first `#include` in a `*.cpp` file is it's associated `*.h` file.  That helps ensure the header file does not have accidental dependencies that were not included.

Answer (score 3):

It is common practise to include `file.h` in any file where `foo` or `bar` are needed and drop the duplicate declarations.  Then, if a function's signature changes (or if a new function is added) it only needs to be changed in one place.  It also avoids the danger of declaring a function in two different places with two different signatures.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I include the header containing the definition of a namespace in source files?

Technically, including a header file is the same thing as copying the content of that file into the other and thus it is entirely possible to write a program without using any header files. I suggest that you don't do that.

Every declaration that you use in more than one translation unit, you should declare in a header file, and include in each translation unit that use the declaration.

> So in those source files am I opening an existing namespace

Namespaces with same name in different translation units are the same namespace. Only an anonymous namespace is unique to the translation unit where it is declared.